# SwiftUI transition from modal sheet to regular view with Navigation Link

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, modalviewcontroller, ios-navigationview

I'm working with SwiftUI and I have a starting page. When a user presses a button on this page, a modal sheet pops up.

In side the modal sheet, I have some code like this:

```
  NavigationLink(destination: NextView(), tag: 2, selection: $tag) {
            EmptyView()
    }
```

and my modal sheet view is wrapped inside of a Navigation View.

When the value of tag becomes 2, the view does indeed go to NextView(), but it's also presented as a modal sheet that the user can swipe down from, and I don't want this.

I'd like to transition from a modal sheet to a regular view.

Is this possible? I've tried hiding the navigation bar, etc. but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any help with this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have `view A` which has a button upon pressing it `View B` is presented as modal, but when pressing something in `View B` you want `View A` to navigate to it?

Comment: Hmm yeah I guess thats a good way of putting it. Like I watch to get out of the model view B and transition to some other view C (which is non modal)

Comment: By wrapping the modal sheet in a NavigationView you are assigning it its own UINavigationController and all navigation links within the modal sheet will be managed by that controller. You might be better using a Binding variable on your modal sheet to trigger a navigation link within the view that presented your sheet. But for it to work, you would probably need to first dismiss the modal  sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by creating an `environmentObject` and bind the `navigationLink` destination value to the `environmentObject`'s value then change the value of the `environmentObject` in the modal view.

Here is a code explaining what I mean

```
import SwiftUI

class NavigationManager: ObservableObject{
    @Published private(set) var dest: AnyView? = nil
    @Published var isActive: Bool = false

    func move(to: AnyView) {
        self.dest = to
        self.isActive = true
    }
}

struct StackOverflow6: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationManager: NavigationManager
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: self.navigationManager.dest, isActive: self.$navigationManager.isActive) {
                    EmptyView()
                }

                Button(action: {
                    self.showModal.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Show Modal")
                }
            }
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
                secondView(isPresented: self.$showModal).environmentObject(self.navigationManager)
            }
    }
}

struct StackOverflow6_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackOverflow6().environmentObject(NavigationManager())
    }
}


struct secondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationManager: NavigationManager
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var dest: AnyView? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Modal view")
            Button(action: {
                self.isPresented = false
                self.dest = AnyView(thirdView())
            }) {
                Text("Press me to navigate")
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            // This code can run any where but I placed it in `.onDisappear` so you can see the animation
            if let dest = self.dest {
                self.navigationManager.move(to: dest)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct thirdView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("3rd")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("3rd View"))
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, if you have any questions regarding this code, please let me know.